# How to calculate the mean in R with several conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, mean

I am trying to calculate the means of this data frame and group them in a tale! I know how to do that using averageifs in excel but because I want to eventually get the standard deviation and coefficient of variation (CV) I need to learn that in R.

For now I just need the mean. Here are my conditions:

I need a table where the "stim_ending_t" which is my time intervals are arranged from 1.0 to 3.5 in a rows. For time intervals I need these three conditions to be met while calculating the mean which is "key_resp_2.rt"

only image Visibility and soundvolume(V=1 & s=0)

Only Sound (V=0 & s=1)

Blank (V=0 & s=0)

[The data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ext55.png)

[Expected out come](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIZeH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will compute stim_ending_t (6) x modality (3) = 18 group means.

First I generate some data like your `analysis_v` or `analysis_a` data frames:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

analysis_v <- data.frame(stim_ending_t = rep(seq(1, 3.5, 0.5), each = 30), 
                         visbility = rep(c(1, 0, 0), 60), 
                         soundvolume = rep(c(0, 1, 0), 60), 
                         key_resp_2.rt = runif(180, 1, 5))
```

Then I pipe the object into the code block:

```
analysis_v %>% 
  group_by(stim_ending_t, visbility, soundvolume) %>% 
  summarize(average = mean(key_resp_2.rt)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(key = case_when(visbility == 0 & soundvolume == 0 ~ "blank", 
                         visbility == 0 & soundvolume == 1 ~ "only_sound", 
                         visbility == 1 & soundvolume == 0 ~ "only_images")) %>% 
  select(-visbility, -soundvolume) %>% 
  spread(key, average)
```

Which results in the requested output format:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  stim_ending_t blank only_images only_sound
          <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1           1    3.28        3.55       2.84
2           1.5  2.64        3.11       2.32
3           2    3.27        3.72       2.42
4           2.5  2.14        3.01       2.30
5           3    2.47        3.03       3.02
6           3.5  2.93        2.92       2.78
```

You would need to repeat the code block using `analysis_a` to get those means.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am only getting a table of 6 * 4 outcome only? Also, the number I got from my excel using "AVERAGEIFS" are different from the one I got from the 6*4 table? Any thoughts why?

Comment: There are six rows because you have six levels of interval (i.e., 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, and 3.5). There are four columns because there is a column for interval, and group means for only images, only sounds, and blank. This format matches the [expected output format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIZeH.png) showing 6x4.

Comment: To investigate why the output is different from Excel please share the code used to read your data into R.

Comment: # subseting the data to based on the modality: V & A. While p1 is the original data frame 
`p1_visual <- p1[p1$Opening_text=="For these trials attend to Visual", ]`
`p1_auditory <- p1[p1$Opening_text=="For these trials attend to Auditory", ]`

 # creating a victor for the visual variables
 `blank_V <- c('stim_ending_t','visbility','soundvolume','key_resp_2.rt')`

 # create data frame for only visual variables
`analysis_v <- p1_visual[blank_V]`  

# I did similar thing for A and then used you code and changed `your_data ` with   `analysis_A`
Let me know if this is what you asked for?

Comment: Please share the output of head(p1)

Comment: too long characters that can not be posted here!
Here is the link: [link](https://imgur.com/RkcvMAe) & [link](https://imgur.com/gog8TKS)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help @Matthew Schuelke, but with your code I was getting different results every time I run the code.

Here is how I solved the problem with this code:

```
name of the new data = (name of the data frame without the parentheses) %>%
  group_by(stim_ending_t, visbility, soundvolume, Opening_text) %>%
  summarize(m = mean(key_resp_2.rt),
            sd = sd(key_resp_2.rt),
            coefVar = cv(key_resp_2.rt))
```

The result as I wanted:

```
stim_ending_t visbility soundvolume Opening_text               m     sd coefVar
          <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1             1         0           0 Now focus on the Image  1.70  1.14    0.670
2             1         0           0 Now focus on the Sound  1.57  0.794   0.504
3             1         0           1 Now focus on the Image  1.62  1.25    0.772
4             1         0           1 Now focus on the Sound  1.84  1.17    0.637
5             1         1           0 Now focus on the Image  3.19 17.2     5.38 
6             1         1           0 Now focus on the Sound  1.59  0.706   0.444
```

Comment: Of course you were getting different output every time you ran my code. My code generates random data every time because I only had a picture of a very small percentage of your data to work from. It would be better to provide a larger percent of your data as text that can be directly copied and pasted so that others can help you more quickly in the future. Also, that output does not match what you asked for [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIZeH.png). It would be better to be more explicit about what your end goal is so that others can better help you in the future.

Comment: I am so sorry, but it was my first time using Stackoverflow. I have learned how to ask my questions more concisely, and I have learned a lot from people here. So thank you again for trying to help and please do not feel discouraged to contribute more in future